# where can i find resources files in iphone project ( css, js .. ) 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build

I am using jquery mobile in iPhone application, I have included the resources files in the header like this >>

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
```

but after that, I have removed these three files from the project, but the project still see them as they are still in the project, are they copied to a new place in the project while building the app ?

what is the problem ?!

### edit 1

another problem maybe related to this one, that I have `css` file which has a rules '`background-image:url(images/icons-18-white.png);`' and I have the images folder which has the the required images, but when displaying that in `html`, `css` don't represents the images, why ?!

Comment: You've just asked a completely separate question within the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the files from the left pane in Xcode does not always delete the actual files, so when the application is compiled, the files might still be copied in.

Open Finder and go to the physical location of your project on the disk, and see if the files are there. If they are, you will need to remove them to somewhere else to prevent them from being copied.

If the files are still visible in the left pane in Xcode, select them there and press delete, and select 'Delete Files' in the confirmation box. **Note:** This will delete the actual files so make sure you have a backup or a way to get them back.

**Edit: (to answer second part of question):**
Make sure the images folder is actually a folder on the disk, not just a group in the Xcode file browser. If it isn't, delete the files from Xcode (click 'Delete References', don't delete the actual files), then put them in a physical folder inside the project folder, and re-add the entire folder back to Xcode.

Comment: If this fixes your problem or helps you, remember to click the tick or the up arrow on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted them from xcode (xcode 3), they will still be present in the project folder on the file system, only not visible to the project. So if you try to add them in the project again, they will give you an error. To add them again, right click the project and click add existing files. Do not try to copy them into the project folder on the files system.